# White background behind axis ticks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, backgrounds, axis

I couldn't find any solution to this specific problem, just with nodes.
I want to make a white background behind all xlabel ticks, so the labels can be read again.[image]

My minimal code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn] {scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{
    calc,
    patterns,
    positioning
}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.16,
    samples=200,
    clip=false,
    my axis style/.style={
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        legend pos=outer north east,
        axis line style={
            ->,
        },
        legend style={
            font=\footnotesize
        },
        label style={
            font=\footnotesize
        },
        tick label style={
            font=\footnotesize
        },
        xlabel style={
            at={
                (ticklabel* cs:1)
            },
            anchor=west,
            font=\footnotesize,
        },
        ylabel style={
            at={
                (ticklabel* cs:1)
            },
            anchor=west,
            font=\footnotesize,
        },
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$
    },
}
\tikzset{
    >=stealth
}

\begin{document}
        \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                my axis style,
                width=\textwidth,
                height=.5\textwidth,
                xlabel=$t$ in $s$,
                ylabel=$i_{Sch}$ in $A$,
                %   axis y line*=left,
                ]
                \addplot [smooth, color=blue] table [x=time, y=I(R1)]{
                    time                    I(R1)
                    0.000000000000000e+000  0.000000e+000
                    9.999999717180685e-010  -7.365461e-009
                    1.999999943436137e-009  -1.092396e-008
                    7.999999773744548e-009  -1.261143e-008
                    9.066561145910884e-006  -1.362286e-008
                    1.812512229204802e-005  -1.540520e-008
                    2.718368343818516e-005  -1.795843e-008
                    3.624224458432230e-005  -2.128255e-008
                    4.530080573045944e-005  -2.537758e-008
                    5.435936687659658e-005  -3.024350e-008
                    6.341792802273370e-005  -3.588032e-008
                    7.511397155880838e-005  -4.802314e-008
                    8.765506948961393e-005  -6.784544e-008
                    1.010866443723525e-004  -1.011901e-007
                    1.150555985235115e-004  -1.570309e-007
                    1.295578137087779e-004  -2.520768e-007
                    1.443474506069229e-004  -4.131692e-007
                    1.594219777569360e-004  -6.885666e-007
                    1.746332018172406e-004  -1.157717e-006
                    1.899899246666463e-004  -1.960442e-006
                    2.054121982629859e-004  -3.329848e-006
                    2.209179264293448e-004  -5.669775e-006
                    2.364728323130587e-004  -9.655013e-006
                    2.521069940543570e-004  -1.643361e-005
                    2.678278416879484e-004  -2.789903e-005
                    2.836985201725103e-004  -4.716688e-005
                    2.997968746638052e-004  -7.916512e-005
                    3.162826476351179e-004  -1.314847e-004
                    3.334021764381655e-004  -2.152306e-004
                    3.515756931076850e-004  -3.463514e-004
                    3.714676768684271e-004  -5.470277e-004
                    3.940706856733047e-004  -8.479937e-004
                    4.212006783581084e-004  -1.299121e-003
                    4.555657572551866e-004  -1.978138e-003
                    5.017994118552240e-004  -3.018437e-003
                    5.680584065004804e-004  -4.655581e-003
                    6.632859276716133e-004  -7.161702e-003
                    8.040208018100112e-004  -1.100670e-002
                    1.027433546711530e-003  -1.718358e-002
                    1.385268620168111e-003  -2.688076e-002
                    1.906278184582873e-003  -3.995958e-002
                    2.739750504703908e-003  -5.750819e-002
                    3.739750504703908e-003  -7.342625e-002
                    4.203087967199147e-003  -7.827881e-002
                    4.503975004298807e-003  -7.997190e-002
                    4.870406888153701e-003  -8.071495e-002
                    5.251810149259599e-003  -8.010871e-002
                    5.709862159532873e-003  -7.727358e-002
                    6.452193882543894e-003  -6.841069e-002
                    7.452193882543894e-003  -5.020306e-002
                    8.452193882543894e-003  -2.670933e-002
                    9.045905678963170e-003  -1.101603e-002
                    9.299676990566507e-003  -4.394128e-003
                    9.440993081474430e-003  -1.250610e-003
                    9.493945315094930e-003  -4.601344e-004
                    9.532680403970701e-003  -1.597478e-004
                    9.555324669126297e-003  -7.304467e-005
                    9.570918730826331e-003  -4.337832e-005
                    9.589289786002533e-003  -2.415100e-005
                    9.608994456792324e-003  -1.262891e-005
                    9.629974566007529e-003  -6.322548e-006
                    9.653957781237840e-003  -2.902751e-006
                    9.682193190329275e-003  -1.193113e-006
                    9.719844638599333e-003  -3.985592e-007
                    9.778107440391343e-003  -8.480582e-008
                    9.880104681256332e-003  6.488202e-011
                    1.008409916298631e-002  1.665577e-008
                    1.020021905760590e-002  1.416924e-007
                    1.029680429700099e-002  1.248411e-006
                    1.035416622866545e-002  5.200986e-006
                    1.039146017810288e-002  1.469224e-005
                    1.041813026149294e-002  3.315969e-005
                    1.044183772019748e-002  6.984581e-005
                    1.046509413916068e-002  1.416863e-004
                    1.048999031805958e-002  2.799063e-004
                    1.051551390544428e-002  5.134992e-004
                    1.054902027796938e-002  9.786619e-004
                    1.060456024468278e-002  2.006833e-003
                    1.066250403970733e-002  3.288640e-003
                    1.072826852822862e-002  4.911225e-003
                    1.082693517220759e-002  7.496832e-003
                    1.097786120530155e-002  1.157732e-002
                    1.121587389267865e-002  1.804045e-002
                    1.160624721787907e-002  2.826607e-002
                    1.224714917345807e-002  4.328346e-002
                    1.320104378336704e-002  6.126405e-002
                    1.399778830659167e-002  7.201473e-002
                    1.434984252633140e-002  7.489435e-002
                    1.468373929489571e-002  7.618931e-002
                    1.504537346983024e-002  7.639752e-002
                    1.537388149627724e-002  7.536133e-002
                    1.590825837140517e-002  7.108162e-002
                    1.677122155614463e-002  5.911125e-002
                    1.777122155614463e-002  3.905017e-002
                    1.877122155614463e-002  1.444965e-002
                    1.908992918069155e-002  6.219001e-003
                    1.928764670879647e-002  1.594853e-003
                    1.935231318698496e-002  5.301742e-004
                    1.939198013393608e-002  1.883385e-004
                    1.941963180060979e-002  7.622215e-005
                    1.943827856271483e-002  4.047850e-005
                    1.945831672162536e-002  2.103696e-005
                    1.947722109662591e-002  1.126648e-005
                    1.950001120545947e-002  5.506733e-006
                    1.952902603081474e-002  2.291721e-006
                    1.956940580284941e-002  7.350064e-007
                    1.963081205611957e-002  1.530202e-007
                    1.973920049633925e-002  6.965271e-009
                    1.995597737677860e-002  -2.826031e-008
                    2.038953113765732e-002  -1.393842e-005
                    2.056292042754844e-002  -1.483077e-004
                    2.064027375155921e-002  -4.768932e-004
                    2.068174648716996e-002  -9.273372e-004
                    2.072386184512217e-002  -1.651186e-003
                    2.078181727285966e-002  -2.878171e-003
                    2.084336523345867e-002  -4.341996e-003
                    2.093133141048762e-002  -6.587358e-003
                    2.106507461936032e-002  -1.012989e-002
                    2.127215654288834e-002  -1.566978e-002
                    2.161234590948691e-002  -2.452940e-002
                    2.216750029315237e-002  -3.770044e-002
                    2.303044185208308e-002  -5.447083e-002
                    2.393025682599418e-002  -6.733114e-002
                    2.429947407935129e-002  -7.065765e-002
                    2.462214523878575e-002  -7.214584e-002
                    2.493597259834421e-002  -7.258030e-002
                    2.527619948848180e-002  -7.186820e-002
                    2.574952305777642e-002  -6.877103e-002
                    2.651612238856232e-002  -5.938944e-002
                    2.751612238856233e-002  -4.092745e-002
                    2.851612238856233e-002  -1.757935e-002
                    2.885351174231214e-002  -8.928788e-003
                    2.907899705456984e-002  -3.291205e-003
                    2.917743178763524e-002  -1.243794e-003
                    2.923399754787738e-002  -4.442662e-004
                    2.926827634604691e-002  -1.776766e-004
                    2.929551813135463e-002  -7.396947e-005
                    2.931149090535592e-002  -4.289592e-005
                    2.933002738741820e-002  -2.392698e-005
                    2.934994522346865e-002  -1.255085e-005
                    2.937136554721559e-002  -6.291780e-006
                    2.939702011577487e-002  -2.841328e-006
                    2.943099679277940e-002  -1.056922e-006
                    2.948109720577423e-002  -2.787816e-007
                    2.956268572156585e-002  -3.644846e-008
                    2.972415979546668e-002  7.880048e-009
                    3.004710794326835e-002  7.860178e-006
                    3.069300423887169e-002  8.417835e-004
                    3.087389210007860e-002  2.585605e-003
                    3.101638194364034e-002  5.532479e-003
                    3.112787664704718e-002  8.361294e-003
                    3.124358696142409e-002  1.140374e-002
                    3.147500759017792e-002  1.749802e-002
                    3.170036609554953e-002  2.327096e-002
                    3.212921642289766e-002  3.365120e-002
                    3.254000453417492e-002  4.243362e-002
                    3.332629910502745e-002  5.585216e-002
                    3.408698589444538e-002  6.526487e-002
                    3.441663154982660e-002  6.771243e-002
                    3.476433076696574e-002  6.875271e-002
                    3.521227086920439e-002  6.841774e-002
                    3.564554575662704e-002  6.611338e-002
                    3.634837941627374e-002  5.829891e-002
                    3.734837941627374e-002  4.097483e-002
                    3.834837941627374e-002  1.855639e-002
                    3.875818668069869e-002  8.279039e-003
                    3.896069605108576e-002  3.337808e-003
                    3.907392689743548e-002  1.031947e-003
                    3.911700753741167e-002  4.527585e-004
                    3.915904377648398e-002  1.521342e-004
                    3.918040684822421e-002  7.273034e-005
                    3.919669972705938e-002  4.312677e-005
                    3.921571693312646e-002  2.382288e-005
                    3.923597559395128e-002  1.239714e-005
                    3.925739616666368e-002  6.211195e-006
                    3.928216176240546e-002  2.857231e-006
                    3.931323896560074e-002  1.133441e-006
                    3.935780296432129e-002  3.363974e-007
                    3.942813869280760e-002  5.716958e-008
                    3.955925809095569e-002  -4.643006e-009
                    3.982149688725187e-002  -9.988301e-009
                    4.034597447984423e-002  -4.660966e-008
                    4.062707866241308e-002  -6.371707e-006
                    4.078024754688465e-002  -7.545964e-005
                    4.085483257646507e-002  -2.593282e-004
                    4.088993844904794e-002  -5.124083e-004
                    4.092712804471944e-002  -9.950561e-004
                    4.097593752058149e-002  -1.863046e-003
                    4.104179844736999e-002  -3.268345e-003
                    4.110553631326639e-002  -4.778726e-003
                    4.120581835993196e-002  -7.301650e-003
                    4.135707856049486e-002  -1.120552e-002
                    4.159560781330517e-002  -1.733320e-002
                    4.198234762246771e-002  -2.676272e-002
                    4.261901720869422e-002  -4.023692e-002
                    4.356317944205046e-002  -5.591744e-002
                    4.413678123914961e-002  -6.251917e-002
                    4.445403843047479e-002  -6.461293e-002
                    4.480967062731011e-002  -6.556032e-002
                    4.522918685184976e-002  -6.513377e-002
                    4.567306480803018e-002  -6.265096e-002
                    4.639281956959360e-002  -5.447830e-002
                    4.739281956959360e-002  -3.694250e-002
                    4.839281956959360e-002  -1.449649e-002
                    4.878424457079300e-002  -4.997892e-003
                    4.895565238730473e-002  -1.336899e-003
                    4.902807962211532e-002  -3.377555e-004
                    4.906444439243231e-002  -1.085708e-004
                    4.908835931930602e-002  -4.822782e-005
                    4.910706411123867e-002  -2.601051e-005
                    4.912682509704375e-002  -1.393869e-005
                    4.914966884631109e-002  -6.883342e-006
                    4.917849921537330e-002  -2.923551e-006
                    4.921776830572505e-002  -9.777650e-007
                    4.927655958322968e-002  -2.216076e-007
                    4.937768216005434e-002  -1.883350e-008
                    4.957992731370365e-002  8.971623e-009
                    4.998441762100228e-002  1.605754e-007
                    5.079339823559954e-002  2.930285e-004
                    5.102042749962474e-002  1.254297e-003
                    5.111738095098622e-002  2.626969e-003
                    5.121147735746362e-002  4.725882e-003
                    5.132477079720533e-002  7.513491e-003
                    5.144697324026087e-002  1.061400e-002
                    5.163987859681987e-002  1.552924e-002
                    5.182858254447589e-002  2.023190e-002
                    5.214540438884140e-002  2.771406e-002
                    5.260146045613007e-002  3.715342e-002
                    5.351357259070740e-002  5.204988e-002
                    5.420444579099952e-002  5.993531e-002
                    5.450499904609398e-002  6.183306e-002
                    5.487165478753637e-002  6.264354e-002
                    5.525227461383028e-002  6.211113e-002
                    5.571061754142893e-002  5.936832e-002
                    5.645341211902161e-002  5.067939e-002
                    5.745341211902161e-002  3.284556e-002
                    5.845341211902161e-002  1.042107e-002
                    5.878676105944519e-002  2.835768e-003
                    5.892711994804607e-002  4.483291e-004
                    5.897138543553375e-002  9.852399e-005
                    5.899704137203902e-002  3.935740e-005
                    5.901651058044655e-002  2.049229e-005
                    5.903590352005603e-002  1.108962e-005
                    5.905910204503470e-002  5.493866e-006
                    5.908969251481638e-002  2.262168e-006
                    5.913186933633605e-002  7.138320e-007
                    5.919565851265094e-002  1.473483e-007
                    5.930961577084798e-002  6.973750e-009
                    5.953753028724206e-002  -9.242352e-009
                    5.999335932003021e-002  -2.559174e-007
                    6.090501738560653e-002  -1.535099e-004
                    6.108427471328602e-002  -8.017753e-004
                    6.119171058306677e-002  -2.164489e-003
                    6.129492589054789e-002  -4.312806e-003
                    6.139714319077896e-002  -6.754496e-003
                    6.150334496254062e-002  -9.396303e-003
                    6.168632666583152e-002  -1.398502e-002
                    6.186716864392511e-002  -1.843040e-002
                    6.219009375724363e-002  -2.596756e-002
                    6.263066842061660e-002  -3.501825e-002
                    6.349272072685612e-002  -4.905576e-002
                    6.418703867526103e-002  -5.703357e-002
                    6.449187528364359e-002  -5.901393e-002
                    6.485566926573663e-002  -5.987399e-002
                    6.524632386927226e-002  -5.938118e-002
                    6.570093929581984e-002  -5.672584e-002
                    6.643780172320625e-002  -4.820940e-002
                    6.743780172320625e-002  -3.069104e-002
                    6.831438278034990e-002  -1.135406e-002
                    6.860155693769555e-002  -4.638609e-003
                    6.876883366709015e-002  -1.182886e-003
                    6.882485403438028e-002  -4.119988e-004
                    6.886342976037657e-002  -1.456477e-004
                    6.888550034819810e-002  -7.075111e-005
                    6.890236439956540e-002  -4.180888e-005
                    6.892211431928021e-002  -2.294974e-005
                    6.894299158140817e-002  -1.191642e-005
                    6.896520795167596e-002  -5.937600e-006
                    6.899093028596363e-002  -2.716194e-006
                    6.902387657687870e-002  -1.054671e-006
                    6.907146132894873e-002  -3.012283e-007
                    6.914725269896939e-002  -4.741947e-008
                    6.929132764149532e-002  5.386693e-009
                    6.957947752654715e-002  9.261282e-009
                    7.015577729665085e-002  4.072689e-005
                    7.115577729665085e-002  1.816542e-003
                    7.138662258787804e-002  4.591296e-003
                    7.160239294030832e-002  9.459953e-003
                    7.177933410847702e-002  1.379581e-002
                    7.197813750406129e-002  1.855936e-002
                    7.237574429522985e-002  2.755491e-002
                    7.274931836914111e-002  3.500187e-002
                    7.345651296661251e-002  4.630834e-002
                    7.409757700445388e-002  5.380790e-002
                    7.442458067454415e-002  5.614941e-002
                    7.477395396418131e-002  5.720763e-002
                    7.521586353082205e-002  5.690420e-002
                    7.565139065126517e-002  5.461903e-002
                    7.635782082067928e-002  4.684114e-002
                    7.735782082067928e-002  2.989124e-002
                    7.823924423217327e-002  1.092039e-002
                    7.854966193787580e-002  3.861686e-003
                    7.870387818219465e-002  8.928127e-004
                    7.875689398067395e-002  2.984293e-004
                    7.880996008787340e-002  6.150063e-005
                    7.882612750739862e-002  3.166012e-005
                    7.884515577372071e-002  1.780544e-005
                    7.886604928760004e-002  9.376546e-006
                    7.889026157902329e-002  4.460413e-006
                    7.891757117401888e-002  1.937143e-006
                    7.895108209960788e-002  7.377647e-007
                    7.900014688320330e-002  2.059365e-007
                    7.908000841212730e-002  2.843881e-008
                    7.923380457692426e-002  -6.893099e-009
                    7.954139690651818e-002  -9.080973e-009
                    8.015658156570601e-002  -3.505842e-006
                    8.115658156570602e-002  -9.943349e-004
                    8.139439417555475e-002  -3.079206e-003
                    8.157136759687578e-002  -6.529284e-003
                    8.170441244708114e-002  -9.702990e-003
                    8.184403607339368e-002  -1.307092e-002
                    8.212328332601875e-002  -1.964143e-002
                    8.240528626287906e-002  -2.583533e-002
                    8.291145870240935e-002  -3.556658e-002
                    8.353104150009534e-002  -4.510106e-002
                    8.413030020583830e-002  -5.175180e-002
                    8.444916508369876e-002  -5.392544e-002
                    8.480375594052381e-002  -5.492485e-002
                    8.522698162245042e-002  -5.456049e-002
                    8.566947754772317e-002  -5.216050e-002
                    8.638702830151100e-002  -4.415259e-002
                    8.738702830151100e-002  -2.719150e-002
                    8.818592180049750e-002  -1.013178e-002
                    8.843353183098590e-002  -4.522248e-003
                    8.859573814780064e-002  -1.238988e-003
                    8.864841305371904e-002  -5.051317e-004
                    8.869347809528190e-002  -1.720275e-004
                    8.871945001403246e-002  -7.552758e-005
                    8.873899259015466e-002  -4.135863e-005
                    8.876083351070432e-002  -2.127622e-005
                    8.878108965731434e-002  -1.129868e-005
                    8.880461949308628e-002  -5.601813e-006
                    8.883431836929552e-002  -2.394615e-006
                    8.887540883477620e-002  -7.962258e-007
                    8.893694498658604e-002  -1.769274e-007
                    8.904298599992551e-002  -1.331931e-008
                    8.925506802660445e-002  8.463911e-009
                    8.967923207996234e-002  8.857818e-009
                    9.052756018667812e-002  9.094482e-009
                    9.090133843229807e-002  1.408624e-007
                    9.111743907251400e-002  9.987441e-006
                    9.125280489864561e-002  6.299149e-005
                    9.129930443493692e-002  1.551735e-004
                    9.133073087379560e-002  3.190788e-004
                    9.136451846112426e-002  6.317103e-004
                    9.140137345034245e-002  1.136521e-003
                    9.145922931673202e-002  2.159047e-003
                    9.152007807775561e-002  3.408788e-003
                    9.159529300472988e-002  5.099308e-003
                    9.170740104267010e-002  7.733193e-003
                    9.187728162639539e-002  1.176728e-002
                    9.214842987780600e-002  1.802041e-002
                    9.258466452597353e-002  2.715013e-002
                    9.328682352870034e-002  3.919437e-002
                    9.403118588587137e-002  4.863236e-002
                    9.437481608497855e-002  5.137511e-002
                    9.471381741738905e-002  5.262242e-002
                    9.513525262678457e-002  5.267696e-002
                    9.552020878878330e-002  5.111137e-002
                    9.614561255771890e-002  4.512652e-002
                    9.714561255771891e-002  2.951912e-002
                    9.814561255771891e-002  9.146073e-003
                    9.843055785032613e-002  3.116602e-003
                    9.858859104008622e-002  4.909054e-004
                    9.863258809757303e-002  1.248405e-004
                    9.866373874166728e-002  4.414790e-005
                    9.867905962942838e-002  2.652846e-005
                    9.870216840741145e-002  1.349019e-005
                    9.872346355793192e-002  6.971317e-006
                    9.875002115562800e-002  3.162000e-006
                    9.877934560740014e-002  1.311493e-006
                    9.881650369567592e-002  4.468088e-007
                    9.886214403847936e-002  1.175905e-007
                    9.892326947932939e-002  1.768716e-008
                    9.902319442459147e-002  -5.768995e-009
                    9.922304431511562e-002  -8.823709e-009
                    9.962274409616392e-002  -8.692487e-009
                    1.002252045584292e-001  -1.453861e-008
                    1.011074053983750e-001  -1.459810e-004
                    1.014190851890495e-001  -1.073895e-003
                    1.015555032016123e-001  -2.732144e-003
                    1.016872984492505e-001  -5.454067e-003
                    1.018132434550168e-001  -8.354891e-003
                    1.019455891507019e-001  -1.144951e-002
                    1.021814329902172e-001  -1.687047e-002
                    1.024152256483736e-001  -2.195589e-002
                    1.028308758464857e-001  -3.006204e-002
                    1.033804109491158e-001  -3.883344e-002
                    1.040672565576073e-001  -4.698115e-002
                    1.044018341433195e-001  -4.951802e-002
                    1.047464343478554e-001  -5.065945e-002
                    1.052055858994108e-001  -5.046130e-002
                    1.056346695417774e-001  -4.832585e-002
                    1.063308071885852e-001  -4.085298e-002
                    1.073308071885852e-001  -2.431535e-002
                    1.081915336752392e-001  -6.818481e-003
                    1.085126543571578e-001  -6.281485e-004
                    1.085587613078550e-001  -1.632182e-004
                    1.086258789096746e-001  -2.425363e-005
                    1.086483823978971e-001  -8.433788e-006
                    1.086708135536323e-001  -4.333561e-006
                    1.087035300450450e-001  -1.851824e-006
                    1.087583759146351e-001  -5.101537e-007
                    1.088446216812326e-001  -7.291531e-008
                    1.090088449936499e-001  4.226983e-009
                    1.093372916184846e-001  8.675890e-009
                    1.099941848681539e-001  8.567265e-009
                    1.109941848681539e-001  2.982335e-006
                    1.113507305282164e-001  1.939647e-004
                    1.115045214781672e-001  7.800136e-004
                    1.115685170447898e-001  1.512885e-003
                    1.116331547431547e-001  2.692556e-003
                    1.117128496266127e-001  4.370606e-003
                    1.117968368523681e-001  6.256321e-003
                    1.119457674213939e-001  9.682487e-003
                    1.121648387602566e-001  1.464678e-002
                    1.125199823086976e-001  2.214697e-002
                    1.130953367904625e-001  3.232205e-002
                    1.139716843310007e-001  4.411013e-002
                    1.143303519823945e-001  4.726222e-002
                    1.146603136665457e-001  4.874719e-002
                    1.149626841010554e-001  4.916304e-002
                    1.152861298348121e-001  4.850107e-002
                    1.157656684971885e-001  4.541598e-002
                    1.165421263241865e-001  3.607769e-002
                    1.175421263241865e-001  1.875880e-002
                    1.180242223634477e-001  8.641744e-003
                    1.182396265953623e-001  3.932376e-003
                    1.183681660913633e-001  1.425719e-003
                    1.184208914534897e-001  6.624727e-004
                    1.184646160949299e-001  2.848557e-004
                    1.185077115765924e-001  8.864942e-005
                    1.185272512610068e-001  4.573673e-005
                    1.185467483665663e-001  2.583226e-005
                    1.185685128562118e-001  1.358359e-005
                    1.185916174585170e-001  6.802240e-006
                    1.186177284659855e-001  3.175717e-006
                    1.186510786369555e-001  1.264182e-006
                    1.186979437604904e-001  3.820108e-007
                    1.187722349974043e-001  6.823910e-008
                    1.189076312374732e-001  -2.312126e-009
                    1.191784237176108e-001  -8.574473e-009
                    1.197200086778861e-001  -8.436335e-009
                    1.207200086778861e-001  -1.414187e-008
                    1.212192965570451e-001  -2.383767e-005
                    1.214877697949220e-001  -3.698358e-004
                    1.216033943951865e-001  -1.177110e-003
                    1.216833948193877e-001  -2.388012e-003
                    1.217606511736066e-001  -3.938033e-003
                    1.218426379494396e-001  -5.733533e-003
                    1.219665402398337e-001  -8.533668e-003
                    1.221783032544586e-001  -1.328741e-002
                    1.224868054545341e-001  -1.982374e-002
                    1.230016925262435e-001  -2.919153e-002
                    1.238103358638604e-001  -4.073001e-002
                    1.242294348523194e-001  -4.487389e-002
                    1.245350144334637e-001  -4.656638e-002
                    1.249142469749063e-001  -4.735931e-002
                    1.252681206724392e-001  -4.682834e-002
                    1.257363867163336e-001  -4.398062e-002
                    1.264949560544714e-001  -3.510354e-002
                    1.274949560544714e-001  -1.812780e-002
                    1.279845364831597e-001  -8.028471e-003
                    1.281835420741393e-001  -3.765225e-003
                    1.283120529791679e-001  -1.314006e-003
                    1.283581308834876e-001  -6.677971e-004
                    1.284054584255767e-001  -2.753857e-004
                    1.284492171761173e-001  -8.482493e-005
                    1.284720239913461e-001  -3.992946e-005
                    1.284948000307173e-001  -2.021578e-005
                    1.285158077429051e-001  -1.082158e-005
                    1.285426223341658e-001  -5.113412e-006
                    1.285770630829126e-001  -2.012895e-006
                    1.286258880044308e-001  -5.924363e-007
                    1.287015635777985e-001  -1.071609e-007
                    1.288419974974606e-001  -8.585778e-010
                    1.291228653367847e-001  8.453076e-009
                    1.296846010154329e-001  8.333284e-009
                    1.306846010154329e-001  8.486595e-009
                    1.310943793452964e-001  1.367452e-007
                    1.313808570973907e-001  1.554986e-005
                    1.315328881523161e-001  1.207939e-004
                    1.315998114294058e-001  3.464311e-004
                    1.316393088280962e-001  6.738903e-004
                    1.316805102885297e-001  1.225482e-003
                    1.317405359300895e-001  2.255840e-003
                    1.318042882570509e-001  3.515282e-003
                    1.318856172133218e-001  5.257098e-003
                    1.320060544781967e-001  7.930373e-003
                    1.321908989604754e-001  1.203005e-002
                    1.324816389912973e-001  1.817039e-002
                    1.329534818085395e-001  2.688334e-002
                    1.336942795848261e-001  3.777578e-002
                    1.341860741970808e-001  4.291815e-002
                    1.344911484090323e-001  4.479864e-002
                    1.348547843440503e-001  4.571125e-002
                    1.352459943852937e-001  4.528138e-002
                    1.357004034096795e-001  4.271177e-002
                    1.364369372543723e-001  3.438080e-002
                    1.374369372543723e-001  1.786921e-002
                    1.378874615880574e-001  8.770829e-003
                    1.381118977993172e-001  3.987917e-003
                    1.382378280809525e-001  1.570765e-003
                    1.382970267915723e-001  7.039291e-004
                    1.383389482701878e-001  3.247984e-004
                    1.383851911502079e-001  9.837886e-005
                    1.384026902339130e-001  5.466590e-005
                    1.384216151518037e-001  3.225915e-005
                    1.384446010803651e-001  1.669428e-005
                    1.384671680910056e-001  8.536747e-006
                    1.384927170663955e-001  4.063280e-006
                    1.385222627412295e-001  1.735138e-006
                    1.385579243010262e-001  6.327907e-007
                    1.386025568653598e-001  1.910821e-007
                    1.386726621180397e-001  3.444886e-008
                    1.388023454564689e-001  -4.443014e-009
                    1.390617121333275e-001  -8.401085e-009
                    1.395804454870446e-001  -8.251020e-009
                    1.405804454870446e-001  -8.981726e-006
                    1.415804454870446e-001  -1.566540e-003
                    1.418914592456255e-001  -4.746919e-003
                    1.421892462701684e-001  -1.058734e-002
                    1.423911472186037e-001  -1.493564e-002
                    1.426113753198885e-001  -1.939978e-002
                    1.430518315224583e-001  -2.737070e-002
                    1.435230426900844e-001  -3.423320e-002
                    1.442025685110705e-001  -4.142225e-002
                    1.445035832565194e-001  -4.336867e-002
                    1.448699295282358e-001  -4.425218e-002
                    1.452516324739656e-001  -4.380075e-002
                    1.457095731964507e-001  -4.117288e-002
                    1.464517278529154e-001  -3.273259e-002
                    1.474517278529154e-001  -1.625133e-002
                    1.478551657679239e-001  -8.203923e-003
                    1.481181265494558e-001  -2.736901e-003
                    1.482021142738697e-001  -1.271450e-003
                    1.482717237158745e-001  -4.451485e-004
                    1.483157180169771e-001  -1.598117e-004
                    1.483534639739270e-001  -5.463706e-005
                    1.483787805474527e-001  -2.459985e-005
                    1.484040746090261e-001  -1.189970e-005
                    1.484348253379981e-001  -5.165969e-006
                    1.484767230174230e-001  -1.780310e-006
                    1.485386653880646e-001  -4.253637e-007
                    1.486432223334420e-001  -4.938799e-008
                    1.488523362241968e-001  6.433476e-009
                    1.492705640057064e-001  8.249077e-009
                    1.501070195687256e-001  8.149524e-009
                    1.511070195687256e-001  8.277004e-008
                    1.514634855376502e-001  3.220162e-005
                    1.516706315276831e-001  2.362999e-004
                    1.517381332478318e-001  5.872639e-004
                    1.517909119506885e-001  1.193713e-003
                    1.518439667526876e-001  2.059094e-003
                    1.519242740047465e-001  3.601526e-003
                    1.519995087191000e-001  5.166312e-003
                    1.521225338275576e-001  7.822086e-003
                    1.523108222432302e-001  1.186741e-002
                    1.526010483032491e-001  1.776864e-002
                    1.530761337582858e-001  2.611378e-002
                    1.538179819222979e-001  3.640373e-002
                    1.542322849372485e-001  4.043065e-002
                    1.545385627957829e-001  4.212477e-002
                    1.549186381389739e-001  4.292480e-002
                    1.552697537375197e-001  4.240545e-002
                    1.557390422063247e-001  3.956592e-002
                    1.564992354286154e-001  3.072133e-002
                    1.574992354286154e-001  1.408286e-002
                    1.578507760660743e-001  7.091513e-003
                    1.580505308124991e-001  3.017158e-003
                    1.581546264878551e-001  1.191464e-003
                    1.582073733958107e-001  5.271456e-004
                    1.582461375977511e-001  2.383164e-004
                    1.582841250482872e-001  8.635155e-005
                    1.583013574337799e-001  5.033721e-005
                    1.583213225011886e-001  2.914836e-005
                    1.583443939701607e-001  1.517477e-005
                    1.583680311582008e-001  7.635132e-006
                    1.583943625880974e-001  3.597544e-006
                    1.584254877824028e-001  1.496142e-006
                    1.584627270114669e-001  5.314166e-007
                    1.585102148243198e-001  1.443956e-007
                    1.585707570808143e-001  2.358559e-008
                    1.586534354233108e-001  -3.840426e-009
                    1.587970744748734e-001  -8.094891e-009
                    1.590843525779986e-001  -8.216882e-009
                    1.595254413630961e-001  -8.068133e-009
                    1.602057930713803e-001  -8.067546e-009
                    1.612057930713803e-001  -2.754460e-008
                    1.614657353315047e-001  -1.392217e-005
                    1.616970535697440e-001  -1.366957e-004
                    1.617624307045574e-001  -3.661095e-004
                    1.618146027998332e-001  -8.271448e-004
                    1.618626695515101e-001  -1.494552e-003
                    1.619264128537638e-001  -2.607907e-003
                    1.619946503381943e-001  -3.947943e-003
                    1.620890236788012e-001  -5.920813e-003
                    1.622285766087287e-001  -8.897897e-003
                    1.624468160393225e-001  -1.346004e-002
                    1.627887764567042e-001  -2.004174e-002
                    1.633453552695736e-001  -2.879510e-002
                    1.641877107078731e-001  -3.854099e-002
                    1.644923817751683e-001  -4.066072e-002
                    1.648562859140291e-001  -4.158288e-002
                    1.652465534625436e-001  -4.116834e-002
                    1.657013127146730e-001  -3.861763e-002
                    1.664384040993712e-001  -3.033835e-002
                    1.674384040993712e-001  -1.404894e-002
                    1.678615311551150e-001  -5.770036e-003
                    1.680148527020318e-001  -2.758720e-003
                    1.681280154901263e-001  -8.819880e-004
                    1.681645244946793e-001  -4.843138e-004
                    1.682273739434113e-001  -1.316912e-004
                    1.682569359772345e-001  -5.038248e-005
                    1.682842827465289e-001  -2.299604e-005
                    1.683114648309708e-001  -1.064686e-005
                    1.683440877744973e-001  -4.464404e-006
                    1.683891721957925e-001  -1.469125e-006
                    1.684572873254452e-001  -3.237911e-007
                    1.685757206143910e-001  -2.941776e-008
                    1.688125871922825e-001  7.379315e-009
                    1.692863203480655e-001  8.073559e-009
                    1.702337866596316e-001  8.016107e-009
                    1.712337866596316e-001  4.013187e-007
                    1.716128752268680e-001  4.276445e-005
                    1.717748375821400e-001  2.372218e-004
                    1.718366874082840e-001  5.731943e-004
                    1.718894589372486e-001  1.171213e-003
                    1.719424558416716e-001  2.011901e-003
                    1.720225821253251e-001  3.509064e-003
                    1.720979103186311e-001  5.033851e-003
                };
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried this but doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Have you tried the full solution, with the addition of the option `set layers=tick labels on top` and the `layer set` definition below? Because with dummy values, it works. In addition, your example is difficult to reproduce without the data that you are trying to plot.

Comment: I tried again, but it won't work for me. I now added just the first few datapoints due to Stack Overflow restrictions.

Comment: Instead of just saying, try *showing the code* where you applied the change suggested in the linked post and the resulting output

Answer (score 5):

You just need to add `xticklabel style = {fill=white}, set layers = axis on top` to your `\pgfplotset`.

[image]

```
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.16,
    samples=200,
    clip=false,
    my axis style/.style={
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        legend pos=outer north east,
        axis line style={
            ->,
        },
        legend style={
            font=\footnotesize
        },
        label style={
            font=\footnotesize
        },
        tick label style={
            font=\footnotesize
        },
        xlabel style={
            at={
                (ticklabel* cs:1)
            },
            anchor=west,
            font=\footnotesize,
        },
        ylabel style={
            at={
                (ticklabel* cs:1)
            },
            anchor=west,
            font=\footnotesize,
        },
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        xticklabel style = {fill=white}, set layers = axis on top
    },
}
```

Comment: +1 `axis on top` is a option you can give directly to `axis`. I do not know `set layers = axis on top` or if it is different in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly of topic, but you may liked. Code is a little bit shorter, tick labels are in fixed format

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn] {scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.18}
\tikzset{>=stealth}

\begin{document}
        \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=\textwidth,height=.5\textwidth,
    %
    axis lines=center,
    axis on top,                    % <---
    legend pos=outer north east,
    legend style={font=\footnotesize},
    tick label style={fill=white,   % <--- 
                      font=\footnotesize},
    xlabel=$t$ in $s$, 
    ylabel=$i_{\mathrm{Sch}}$ in $A$,    
        label style={anchor=west},
    xmin= 0,    xmax=0.19,
    ymin=-0.1,  ymax=0.1,   ytick={-0.1,-0.05,0,0.05, 0.1},
    extra y ticks = {0},
    tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,
                      fixed, fixed zerofill,precision=2},
    ]
\addplot [thick, smooth, color=blue] table [x=time, y=I(R1)]{
        time                    I(R1)
        0.000000000000000e+000  0.000000e+000
% table is to huge that can be fit in answer
        1.720979103186311e-001  5.033851e-003
    };
\end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]