# PGF axis label background is covering axis ticks

Tags: pgfplots

Related question: [White background behind axis ticks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/641543/white-background-behind-axis-ticks)

I use a lot of worksheets with Cartesian coordinates. I like using PGF because it graphs functions for me. I have a few small things that I would like to change in this MWE, including that the label backgrounds are covering tick marks:

When I don't put fill=white on the labels, it's hard to read, especially when printed. When I put them in, it covers up the tick marks on the axis. For the ticks, I handled this by decreasing the inner sep and then shifting the labels. Is there a cleaner way to do that, especially for the axis labels?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{every x tick label/.append style={font=\tiny, yshift=-0.2ex, fill=white, inner sep=0.1}}
\pgfplotsset{every y tick label/.append style={font=\tiny, xshift=-0.2ex, yshift=-0.15ex, fill=white, inner sep=0.1}} %y shift makes negative signs more apparent.
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.9, every minor tick/.append style={very thick, minor tick length=3pt}}
\pgfplotsset{every axis plot/.append style={thick}}

\pgfplotsset{every axis label/.append style={fill=white}}
%HOW DO I MAKE THE x AND y BACKGROUNDS NOT GET IN THE WAY OF THE TICK MARKS?

\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}


    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    grid=both,
    axis lines = middle,
    minor xtick={-10, -9, ..., 10},
    minor ytick={-10, -9, ..., 10},
    xtick={-10, -8, ..., 10},
    ytick={-10, -8, ..., 10},
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = $y$,
    xmin=-10,
    xmax=10,
    ymin=-10, 
    ymax=10,
    samples=500] %increase samples to smooth plot, decrease to improve compilation time

    \addplot[color=blue, , thick] {x^2};


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: basic Cartesian graph where the xlabel and ylabel have a white background covering arrowheads and ticks]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is to extend the axes outside the grid and move their labels.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{every x tick label/.append style={font=\tiny, yshift=-0.2ex, fill=white, inner sep=0.1}}
\pgfplotsset{every y tick label/.append style={font=\tiny, xshift=-0.2ex, yshift=-0.15ex, fill=white, inner sep=0.1}} %y shift makes negative signs more apparent.
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.9, every minor tick/.append style={very thick, minor tick length=3pt}}

\pgfplotsset{every axis plot/.append style={thick}}         
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
    
\begin{document}        
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            grid=both,
            axis line style={->,shorten >=-3ex, shorten <=-2ex}, % added <<<<<<<<<<
            axis lines = middle,
            minor xtick={-10, -9, ..., 10},
            minor ytick={-10, -9, ..., 10},
            xtick={-10, -8, ..., 10},
            ytick={-10, -8, ..., 10},
            xlabel = $x$,
            xlabel style={xshift=3ex}, % added <<<<<<<<<<
            ylabel = $y$,
            ylabel style={yshift=3ex}, % added <<<<<<<<<<
            xmin=-10,
            xmax=10,
            ymin=-10, 
            ymax=10,
            samples=500] %increase samples to smooth plot, decrease to improve compilation time
            
            \addplot[color=blue, , thick] {x^2};            
            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is a variant.

[image: d]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{every x tick label/.append style={font=\tiny, yshift=-0.2ex, fill=white, inner sep=0.1}}
\pgfplotsset{every y tick label/.append style={font=\tiny, xshift=-0.2ex, yshift=-0.15ex, fill=white, inner sep=0.1}} %y shift makes negative signs more apparent.
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.9, every minor tick/.append style={very thick, minor tick length=3pt}}

\pgfplotsset{every axis plot/.append style={thick}}         
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
    
\begin{document}        
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            grid=both,
            axis line style={->,shorten >=-2ex, shorten <=-1.5ex}, % added <<<<<<<<<<
            axis lines = middle,
            minor xtick={-10, -9, ..., 10},
            minor ytick={-10, -9, ..., 10},
            xtick={-10, -8, ..., 10},
            ytick={-10, -8, ..., 10},
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = $y$,
            xlabel style={% added <<<<<<<<<<
                anchor=west,at={(ticklabel* cs:1.0)},
                xshift=1.5ex
            },
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel style={% added <<<<<<<<<<
                anchor=south,
                at={(ticklabel* cs:1.0)},
                yshift=1.5ex
            },
            xmin=-10,
            xmax=10,
            ymin=-10, 
            ymax=10,
            samples=500] %increase samples to smooth plot, decrease to improve compilation time
            
            \addplot[color=blue, , thick] {x^2};            
            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}




\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{every x tick label/.append style={font=\tiny, yshift=-0.2ex, fill=white, inner sep=0.1}}
\pgfplotsset{every y tick label/.append style={font=\tiny, xshift=-0.2ex, yshift=-0.15ex, fill=white, inner sep=0.1}} %y shift makes negative signs more apparent.
\pgfplotsset{width=8cm,compat=1.9, every minor tick/.append style={very thick, minor tick length=3pt}}

\pgfplotsset{every axis plot/.append style={thick}}         
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
    
\begin{document}        
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            grid=both,
            axis line style={->,shorten >=-2ex, shorten <=-1.5ex}, % added <<<<<<<<<<
            axis lines = middle,
            minor xtick={-10, -9, ..., 10},
            minor ytick={-10, -9, ..., 10},
            xtick={-10, -8, ..., 10},
            ytick={-10, -8, ..., 10},
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = $y$,
            xlabel style={% added <<<<<<<<<<
                anchor=west,at={(ticklabel* cs:1.0)},
                xshift=1.5ex
            },
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel style={% added <<<<<<<<<<
                anchor=south,
                at={(ticklabel* cs:1.0)},
                yshift=1.5ex
            },
            xmin=-10,
            xmax=10,
            ymin=-10, 
            ymax=10,
            samples=500] %increase samples to smooth plot, decrease to improve compilation time
            
            \addplot[color=blue, , thick] {x^2};            
            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can do without the white altogether by making the grid lighter  `grid style={draw=gray!20},`

[image: e]

Comment: Extending the arrows was another thing I was going to get around to fixing, so this answer helped kill two birds with one stone! I also took your suggestion to lighten the grid, but to gray!60 instead of gray!20